# docker-compose and using local image with mounted volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have an image I create with Dockerfile

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:latest

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY src /app
```

Now in docker-compose.yml I build this image

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  enginetonic:
    build:
      context: .
    image: enginetonic:compose

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: 'mongodb'
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    restart: always


  monitor-service:
    image: enginetonic:compose
    container_name: monitorService
    command: nodemon monitor/monitor.js
    restart: on-failure

  #common services
  access-token-service:
    image: enginetonic:compose
    container_name: accessTokenService
    command: nodemon service/access-token-service/access-token-service.js
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
```

In all documentation to bind:mount or use volumes I found, it is used with other docker commands

example

```
$ docker service create \
     --mount 'type=volume,src=<VOLUME-NAME>,dst=<CONTAINER-PATH>,volume-driver=local,volume-opt=type=nfs,volume-opt=device=<nfs-server>:<nfs-path>,"volume-opt=o=addr=<nfs-address>,vers=4,soft,timeo=180,bg,tcp,rw"'
    --name myservice \
    <IMAGE>
```

How to use volumes, so that every service that covers the whole `/src/` directory, so that every service I start with nodemon reflects the files changed in the whole source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do a volume map in `docker-compose.yml` like this:

```
volumes:
  - ./app/monitor:/path/to/your/workdir/monitor
```

And adjust the command to use file monitor, like [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon), to restart service when there is any file changes:

```
command: ["nodemon", "/path/to/your/workdir/monitor/monitor.js"]
```

You may need to adjust the nodemon arguments or configs based on what you need.

PS. you do not need to tag/push your image. Simply build it directly in [docker-compose#build](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build)

Comment: Ty I will try this now

Comment: can you, please, elaborate more on `volumes:`
I will update my question now with build part and describe more my use of volumes

Comment: my question is where does the volume: go? inside first image?

Comment: I updated my answer. Please refer to [this doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes). The first part of `:` refers to location on host and the last part refers to the container's. `nodemon`, by default, watches all directories under your current working directory. So, you can just execute `nodemon` in `/path/to/your/workdir`.